# Include Adsense on specific pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, adsense

I have an Adsense code snippet like below and I want to include it only on the pages whose `body` tag has a `class` of `"category"` (`body class="category"`) and I want to place it before `div` called `test` `(.test)`

To do that, I was thinking of using:

```
  if ($("body").hasClass("category")) {

  }
```

But, I am a JS newbie and I got stuck with 2 things:

1. How to show that adsense block (code below) before `div` called test
   (`.test`)
2. If the page has any other `class`, I need that adsense
   code gone from the page.

This is the code for adsense

```
  <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
  <ins class="adsbygoogle"
       style="display:block"
       data-ad-client="ca-pub-641651684125955"
       data-ad-slot="84616945153"
       data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
  <script>
  (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
  </script>
```

I am not a native English speaker but I tried to explain it the best way I could.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

- I am using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for the `ins` code
- I test that there is only one class, "category" and no other class on the class statement - you could also use classList and count them

---

```
if ($("body")[0].className=="category") { 
   $(".test").before(`<ins class="adsbygoogle"
       style="display:block"
       data-ad-client="ca-pub-641651684125955"
       data-ad-slot="84616945153"
       data-ad-format="auto"></ins>`);
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.src = location.protocol+"//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js";
    $("head").append(s);
   (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
});
```

Comment: You do not have apostrophe at the call of append. Also, instead of append, you need to use $(".test").before as specified in the question. FInally, you need to tackle with the case when body has the category class, but has another class as well. I kindly ask you to edit your answer accordingly.

Comment: You are right, I was not aware of this syntax, thanks for pointing that out. This clarifies the first problem, but not the second, nor the third.

Comment: You need a . before test

Comment: hasClass is true if the class is "category somethingelse". And the question seems to ask us to not add AdSense in that case, only when class="category."

Comment: I cannot upvote this answer if it does not tackle with this as well. My answer dealt with it.

Comment: Have a look now

Answer (score 0):

This should be the solution.

```
  if ($("body").hasClass("category")) {
      $(".test").before('  <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script> ' +
  '<ins class="adsbygoogle" ' +
       'style="display:block" ' +
       'data-ad-client="ca-pub-641651684125955" ' +
       'data-ad-slot="84616945153" ' +
       'data-ad-format="auto"></ins> ' +
  '<script> ' +
  '(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({}); ' +
  </script>');
  }
```

If you want to prevent this when the given `class` is present, but there is another `class` as well, then change your `if`:

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].class === "category") {
    //...
}
```